# TypeScript type inference for arrays

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I was using TypeScript 2.9 until quite recently then, along with doing a major upgrade to Angular 8, I also included upgrading TypeScript to 3.5.3.
While I was working on that upgrade, I observed the following type inferencing error in **both** 2.9 and 3.5.3: when defining an anonymous function with **multiple** input parameters (in this case `v1Team`, `v2Team`, and `major`) and **without** explicit types the types of **all** of those--e.g., revealed when hovering over each in VSCode--was shown as the type of the first one in the array. That is, `v1Team` is of type `Team` (as shown), so all three variables were inferred to be of type `Team`, even though the last one, `major`, was **not**. So I had to add explicit types in many places to combat that error.

[image]

Fast-forward to today: I sat down to write-up this issue here, a week after my TypeScript upgrade has been finished, and now the issue is gone! In the next figure, you can see that the inferred type for `major` is not a `Team`, but its correct type.

[image: Inferred type for major]

So my question: could someone point me to a ticket that specifically fixed this issue? I searched through [TypeScript's issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) as best I could, but could not find it. I would just like to have closure on this, knowing that it was real and that it was fixed... otherwise, I would be nervous about it popping up again.

Comment: Could you include a [mcve]? And any images of code should be replaced with or supplemented with plain text, as recommended in the guidelines for [ask] a good question.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz, you are misunderstanding the question. I am not asking for how to fix something; _it has already been fixed_. That's what I want to know about. Thanks, though!

Comment: What, specifically, has been fixed?  This is what needs a text-based code example that someone else can put into an IDE and test.  With such an example I could test the code in TS3.5 (older versions of the compiler still exist and can be used) and then TS3.6 and, hopefully, see the difference you mention.  Then I’d have some basis for proceeding to research the change.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I am not sure if I can supply a minimal example as I am not sure I can reproduce the failure any more. (My project is open source, though, if you wanted to have a go... ;-)